# Chess engine issue with Perft(4) for Kiwipete position

Tags: java

I am writing a chess Engine in Java => https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Deepov

I have tested the move generation with all the positions from the chessprogramming wiki perft page => https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Perft+Results

They all work (for at least depth 4) except the **Kiwipete position**.
FEN: `r3k2r/p1ppqpb1/bn2pnp1/3PN3/1p2P3/2N2Q1p/PPPBBPPP/R3K2R w KQkq -`.

Depth 4 result do not match. I find 4 315 415 nodes and the correct value is 4 085 603.

I don't know where to look because the majority of the hard scenarios (castling, promotion, en passant) were tested on the other positions. I suspect it's something related with the black `h3` pawn, because my programm outputs some error for this pawn.

How to track down this bug?

Comment: I doubt that many people understand your chess position notation. I don't for sure. What most people on here understand is code and program error messages. Unfortunately your post has none of these.

Answer (score 1):

By implementing a divide command. It's a simple modification of perft: instead of showing total nodes it shows the count for each move. With your position this should be the output:

```
90978 │  1. a2a4
75677 │  2. g2g4
94405 │  3. a2a3
81066 │  4. b2b3
77468 │  5. g2g3
79551 │  6. d5d6
79803 │  7. e1c1
86975 │  8. e1g1
83866 │  9. e5g6
93913 │ 10. e5d7
88799 │ 11. e5f7
98524 │ 12. f3h3
77838 │ 13. f3f6
69334 │ 14. e2a6
82759 │ 15. g2h3
97464 │ 16. d5e6
84773 │ 17. c3b1
84782 │ 18. c3d1
91447 │ 19. c3a4
81498 │ 20. c3b5
77431 │ 21. e5d3
77752 │ 22. e5c4
79912 │ 23. e5g4
83885 │ 24. e5c6
79989 │ 25. e1d1
77887 │ 26. e1f1
83348 │ 27. a1b1
83263 │ 28. a1c1
79695 │ 29. a1d1
81563 │ 30. h1f1
84876 │ 31. h1g1
83727 │ 32. f3d3
92505 │ 33. f3e3
94461 │ 34. f3g3
90488 │ 35. f3f4
104992 │ 36. f3f5
83037 │ 37. d2c1
90274 │ 38. d2e3
84869 │ 39. d2f4
87951 │ 40. d2g5
82323 │ 41. d2h6
74963 │ 42. e2d1
88728 │ 43. e2f1
85119 │ 44. e2d3
84835 │ 45. e2c4
79739 │ 46. e2b5
92037 │ 47. f3g4
95034 │ 48. f3h5
4085603 │
```

Comparing your output with a reference one you catch the move causing the error, play it and proceed with depth 3.
A reference output can be obtained by any program with a correct perft/divide implemented, like mine (http://protej.info).

Alex

Comment: I tried that but it did not work because the issue was actually when undoing a promotion move.